# Word 2010 Image Caption List Missing

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I created a document with Word 2010 in which I inserted captions for pictures and cross reference.

I saved the document in my computer and emailed it to a colleague. When she opened the document in her computer, the caption list (numbers which were cross referenced to pictures) was not available and she was not able to add a reference to a picture or change an existing cross reference.

It seems that the caption list is only available in the computer which the document is created.

Comment: Is MS Office same on both computers? & Are the OS same on both?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, I am using word 2003.

in my case, i use my laptop to insert a caption (using my own label). So, working on the word doc on my laptop, i created caption gambar 1.1, gambar 1.2, gambar 1.3,...gambar 2.1, gambar 2.2...etc.

however, i took it home, and use my PC, and when i tried to insert a cross-reference, the label 'gambar' disappear from the cross-reference list.

So what i did was this:.  on my PC, i created a new caption with the label 'gambar', and then insert a caption using the lable at the end of the document, (for example gambar 11.1).

Afterward i tried to insert cross-reference, and somehow the computer read the rest of the caption and included it on the cross-reference list  for me to insert.

Hope this helps.